# groovy csv access

Tags: arrays, list, csv, search, groovy

Forgive me if this is a basic question, I am fairly new to Groovy and have been reading extensive material as well as trying to understand the relevant stuff.

Question:-So I want is to 
search data by any given field value – e.g.: Search by Product name for ex: apple , it should show output like all the row which have apple .

csv file example :-

```
 product_name, shipdate ,  arrivedate, prize
   apple,   10/09/2017, 11/09/2017,  100
   mango,  10/26/2017 ,11/09/2017,  200
   pineapple, 12/10/2017, 12/20/2017,  200
```

More clarification of question :- so just for example if user search prize by 200 it should show 2nd and 3rd row.

```html
    import java.io.File 
class Example { 
   static void main(String[] args) { 
      new File("Example.csv").eachLine {  
         line -> println "$line"; 
      } 
   } 
}
```

from my side i am able to read all csv file but don't know how to search data by field .Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Vampire:- My question is how I will search any field for ex:- prize 200 , so I can get all the row which have 200 prize.output should be print 2nd and 3rd row.

Comment: @priyavenkat, `1)` please provide the code how you load and parse the csv data. btw is it file or what? `2)` provide the data(file) sample - i mean in csv there should be a separator (coma or other).

Comment: @daggett, yes it is csv file which I am parsing after that I am getting output as a coma separator

Comment: @priyavenkat, edit your question, add a code and sample file

Comment: @daggett:- i have added the code , sample file is same as above

Comment: @priyavenkat, the sample file above is not in [CSV (Coma Separated Values)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example) format. Expecting to see `,` (coma) or other field separator

Comment: @daggett,Sorry forgot to change , check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your csv file does not contain complex csv data (with new line or coma in values)

then code could be like this:

```
//the reader could be created from file: file.newReader()
def reader = new StringReader('''product_name,shipdate,arrivedate,prize
apple,10/09/2017,11/09/2017,100
mango,10/26/2017,11/09/2017,200
pineapple,12/10/2017,12/20/2017,200  
''')

def headers=null
reader.splitEachLine(','){line->
    //remove spaces
    line=line.collect{it.trim()}
    if(headers==null){
        //convert headers array to [name:index] map
        headers = line.withIndex().collectEntries()
    }else{
        //print line only when you have a valid value in line
        if( line[ headers['prize'] ]=='200' ){
            println line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @daggett:- But if User searches for all orders with shipDate in October. It should show 1st and 2nd rows . how that will work here.

Comment: use [Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy", value)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) function to convert string value to date. also see the methods of [java Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class to access date fields